# How do I remove a sliding door track that is fasten to the wood somehow?

Tags: repair, removal, closet, fastener

I am trying to do a minor alteration to my sliding closet door of a newly purchased condo. For whatever reason the track of the door has a placement that is recessed from the lip of the door and is not flush. I was thinking it would be simple to just slide the track forward so it looks nicer. I started on unscrewing stuff (see the holes) and I find out they do not support the track. I am not sure how the track is fastened to the wood.

My question is the community is how do i pull this down and reattach? Is it epoxied? I was going to try and hammer it off but I would like a non destructive method of removing it so I can put it back up in a new spot.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Sliding Door Track]

Answer (score 2):

Probably just stuck to the paint due to being installed too soon. Rock it gently and see if it cracks loose.